# Issue with Microdata schema.org on Google Plus

Tags: google-plus, schema.org, microdata

I set the schema.org structure of my webpages like this:

```html
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
 ...some metadate about webpage...
</head>
<body>

<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
...some metadate about newsartilce...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

First I like to know if it is correct?

If yes, I have an issue with this:

When I put my NewsArticle link to Google Plus, it shows like this link in Google Plus:
http://edition.cnn.com/

But when I change the HTML tag to this:

```html
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
```

it shows like this (in article format) in Google Plus:
http://amanpour.blogs.cnn.com/2014/05/01/lagarde-ukraine-loan-not-without-risk/

Do I have to change the structure to this:

```html
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
<head>
...some metadate about newsartilce...
</head>
<body>
....

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have multiple schema.org itemscopes on my page. Which one will the +Snippet use?**

> If multiple schema.org itemscopes are defined on your page, the +Snippet is created from the itemscope that is nearest the top of your page's source code. For example, if you have itemscopes defined on both the body element and a div element defined below the start body tag in your page, the +Snippet is created from the itemscope associated with the body element.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

If you want the page to be interpreted as a NewsArticle by Google you will have to change the initial  `itemtype` in `<html>`.

Comment: So do you recommend me I change itemtype in html for all pages?